# Why is wireless charging safe for phone circuits?

Tags: electromagnetic, induction

Wireless charging is done by electromagnetic induction, by continuously changing magnetic field in a coil, i.e. by passing AC current through it.

I have always been told by others to keep magnets away from electronic devices *(more specifically, one shouldn't move a magnet fast, near a electronic device, that's what I have learnt)*. The reason being:

> Strong changing magnetic field, can induce high EMF and high currents in circuits, causing them to blow-up.

So, how do they save circuits of phone when is charged wirelessly?

Comment: originally, it was asked here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468632/why-is-wireless-charging-safe-for-phone-circuits

Comment: it would take one a heck of a magnet to "blow-up" most circuits like that.

Comment: Can you cite any reliable source telling you not to move a magnet near an electronic device? Also, please define what you mean by "strong" in your quotation.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson it is what everyone tell me, while I play with magnets

Comment: Barry Allen, is that you? Otherwise I don't think you need to worry about moving a magnet near a mobile phone.  (At the outside a strong one might leave residual issues with a compass sensor, but the Google cardboard viewer actually uses a magnet as an input device)

Comment: @Chris Stratton is it same for charging? and no, i am not Barry Allen (i think so :-)

Comment: the main question is about charging..

Comment: The point is that while moving a magnet with your hand, an inductive charger, and the phone's own radio circuitry all involve electromagnetic radiation (as does the light wherever you are reading this), the *frequency* is different - *drastically so*.

Answer (score 1):

Strong magnetic fields can saturate the cores of inductors and transformers allowing much higher than normal currents to flow. this can result in permanent damage.

Flux-gate magnetometers use this effect to sense and measure magnetic fields.

Magnetic storage like disk, tape, and core memory can be erased by strong magnetic fields, electrostatic storasge like flash is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that moving magnetic fields can influence and/or destroy electronics (this field of electronics is called "EMI"). But it depends very much on power and frequency.

Charger and phone are designed in a way that the transfered power is not enough to do any damage, just sufficient for charging. It requires a coil in the phone to pick up the energy, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer) for details.